# Can I use an old bluetooth dongle with a model 2B?

Tags: bluetooth

```
$hciconfig -a
...
...
...
HCI Version: 2.1 (0x4)  Revision: 0x529b
```

Does anyone know if this hardware is incompatible? I got some old bluetooth dongles from work and found my old rpi, it's a model 2 B. The dongle is for bluetooth 1.2. I'm able to connect my laptop and pc with these dongles but I've spent 3 nights so far experimenting with different OSs and config file changes and I cannot get the darned pi to connect to my laptop.

I'm just checking to see if anyone knows if I'm trying to do something that is impossible due to some hardware restriction.

EDIT: Well after two weekends of trying everything I can think of, I quit, maybe someone else can report on their success or failure in the future.

Answer (score -1):

Have you installed and tried the recommended Bluetooth software?

```
sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez-utils blueman bluez python-gobject python-gobject-2
```

Comment: come on now I did rtfm:)